# Serving a Secured File from a Second Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to serve files located in 1 project from a 2nd project through a `self.send_blob` call. These files need to be private except to users who have authenticated (stored user credentials, not Google auth) with the API.

I have 2 projects in app-engine; *project1* is used as an authenticated API and *project2* is used as  a static frontend to serve webpages. The bucket in *project1* has *project2*'s service account in the default object ACL as a READER however the `send_blob` call is silently returning 500 when trying to serve the blob to the authenticated user.

This is how I'm attempting to serve the file

```
blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(gs-filename)
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
self.send_blob(blob_info)
```